# ActiveRecord migration on specific database connection can't rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rollback

TL;DR - Using an explicit database connection in a migration breaks reversibility.

I have a simple migration, adding a column to a specific database connection: (My app has several databases, for good reasons)

```
class AddFlavorToBikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    VehicleBase.connection.tap do |db|
      db.add_column :bikes, :flavor, :string
    end
  end
end
```

This works great:

```
 % be rake db:migrate
== 20181120215337 AddFlavorToBikes: migrating =================================
== 20181120215337 AddFlavorToBikes: migrated (0.0060s) ========================
```

However, it fails to rollback:

```
% be rake db:rollback
== 20181120215337 AddFlavorToBikes: reverting =================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "flavor" of relation "bikes" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "bikes" ADD "flavor" character varying/Users/david/rider-gate/db/migrate/20181120215337_add_flavor_to_bikes.rb:5:in `block in change'
/Users/david/rider-gate/db/migrate/20181120215337_add_flavor_to_bikes.rb:3:in `tap'
/Users/david/rider-gate/db/migrate/20181120215337_add_flavor_to_bikes.rb:3:in `change'
```

I don't understand this. The rollback of db.add_column should *remove* the column. So why am I getting an error that the field I'm trying to remove already exists? *Of course* it exists, that's why I'm trying to remove it.

I searched the Interwebs for a solution, or even anyone with the same problem, and did not find any leads.

I tried using an explicit variable instead of .tap, but got the same error:

```
class AddFlavorToBikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    db = VehicleBase.connection
    db.add_column :bikes, :flavor, :string
  end
end
```

The closest I've been able to discern, ActiveRecord::Migration loses its ability to detect if it is migrating up or down on any but the default ActiveRecord::Base connection.

So, it tries to migrate `add_column` UP, even though it is in a rollback and should be migrating it DOWN. Hence, it is trying to add the column a second time, instead of reversing the add_column into a remove_column.

This is on Rails 4.2.7 and Ruby 2.1.9

How can I make this migration reversible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reasonable solution by splitting `change` into `up` and `down` methods:

```
class AddFlavorToBikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    VehicleBase.connection.tap do |db|
      db.add_column :bikes, :flavor, :string
    end
  end

  def down
    VehicleBase.connection.tap do |db|
      db.remove_column :bikes, :flavor
    end
  end
end
```

While not as graceful or DRY as a reversible migration, this allows db:migrate and db:rollback to work succesfully.